constexpr using concepts, passes for incorrect type
I need a templated function which, at compile time, has some behavior inside of it specialized depending on the template arguments.  I attempted to approach this using an if constexpr, checking for what the type is.  I already have a number of concepts defined for my project, and so I figured I could reuse those, because my understanding was that concepts are evaluated like an expression, producing a prvalue of type bool.
Unfortunately, what I've written doesn't work, as the compiler complains that a static member doesn't exist (which I don't expect one too, but it is as if my concept is returning true in a situation when it should not be).
I have created the following minimal working example:
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

#include "glm/glm.hpp"

template <int N>
class Foo {
public:
    static int length() { return N; };
};

template <typename T>
concept IsFoo = requires(T val)
{
    std::same_as<T, Foo<2>> || std::same_as<T, Foo<3>> || std::same_as<T, Foo<4>>;
};

template <typename T>
void Bar()
{
    // Do some stuff:
    // ...

    // Specialized behavior:
    if constexpr (std::same_as<T, float>) {
        std::cout << "float\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (std::same_as<T, double>) {
        std::cout << "double\n";
    }
    else if constexpr (IsFoo<T>) {
        std::cout << "Foo<" << std::to_string(T::length()) << ">\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "other\n";
    }

    // Do some other stuff:
    // ...
};

int main()
{
    Bar<float>();
    Bar<Foo<3>>();
    Bar<uint8_t>();

    return 0;
};

When compiled with C++20 in Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.11.2), it yields the following errors:
example.cpp(36) : error C2651 : 'uint8_t' : left of '::' must be a class, struct or union
example.cpp(36) : note: the template instantiation context(the oldest one first) is
example.cpp(50) : note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Bar<uint8_t>(void)' being compiled
example.cpp(36) : error C2144 : syntax error : 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ')'
example.cpp(36) : error C2661 : 'std::to_string' : no overloaded function takes 0 arguments
example.cpp(36) : note: while trying to match the argument list '()'
example.cpp(36) : error C2088 : built - in operator '<<' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'
example.cpp(36) : error C2144 : syntax error : 'unknown-type' should be preceded by ';'
example.cpp(36) : error C2039 : 'length' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
example.cpp(36) : error C2059 : syntax error : ')'
example.cpp(36) : error C2143 : syntax error : missing ';' before '<<'
example.cpp(36) : error C2059 : syntax error : '<<'

This looks like it is getting to my instantiation of Bar<uint8_t>(), and then having IsFoo<uint8_t> return true, thus resulting in an attempt to call uint8_t::length(), which of course makes no sense.
What am I missing as to why this doesn't work as I'm expecting?

GCC tells you exactly what's wrong: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/959221e190075d01.  You're missing a requires in your concept.

Rather than having your concept check if T is a Foo<N> specialization, would it make more sense to have it check if T::length() exists?
